# Arrays sort misbehavior for Character array

Tags: java

```
String s5 = "peek";
int i[] = {12, 25, 7, 3, 45};
Arrays.sort(i);

for(int x : i) {
  System.out.print(x + ",");
}

Arrays.sort(s5.toCharArray());

System.out.println(s5); // expected here eekp, but showing peek

for(char c : s5.toCharArray()) {
  System.out.print(c + ",");  //expected here e,e,k,p , but showing p,e,e,k
}
```

Output:

```
3,7,12,25,45,peek
p,e,e,k,
```

for the line `System.out.println(s5)` I expected "eekp" but it's showing "peek".

for the line `System.out.print(c + ",")` I expected "e,e,k,p" but it's showing "p,e,e,k"

Arrays sort seems to work well for integers but not for character array, seems like am doing something wrong. could you please tell me?

Comment: Every time you call `toCharArray` you get a new char array with a *copy* of the string's content. You can't actually alter the content of the string. Strings are immutable.

Comment: hi, after sorting the char array, perhaps create a new string with the sorted value. `char[] chars = s5.toCharArray(); Arrays.sort(chars); String newString = new String(chars);`

Comment: Hint: What does `s5.ToCharArray()` return?

Comment: Specifically: read through [the docs for String.toCharArray](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()): what does it do? How does that differ from what you assumed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Strings are immutable (mostly)

`Arrays.sort(s5.toCharArray());`

The above sorts a copy of the character array and does not modify the actual string value array.

The internal code of `toCharArray` in JDK 1.8

```java
  char result[] = new char[value.length];
  System.arraycopy(value, 0, result, 0, value.length);
```

### Store and sort the copy(new object in a reference)

```java
char[] copy = s5.toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(copy);
```

### Do not try unless for fun

```java
  Field field = String.class.getDeclaredField("value");
  field.setAccessible(true);
  String s5 = "peek";
  Arrays.sort((char[]) field.get(s5));
  System.out.println(s5);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Strings are immutable ***(mostly)***" ? Is there something that I am missing? Because I would like to know.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat, If we use reflection, then we can modify a `String`. the last section of the answer(`Do not try` section) will modify the original `String` object. If we have another reference variable pointing to the same string, then the change is visible to other reference variable also. I have added the complete code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66090999/does-inbuilt-string-methods-usage-create-new-strings/66091135#66091135

Comment: The behavior of `reflection` is slowly changing in Java. With Java 16, code using reflection to access internal JDK apis will result in error by default. I think, its controlled by `--illegal-access=deny` flag. Many frameworks rely on reflection to simplify the user experience(like test frameworks, Dependency injection), so still it might be needed. Basically at current level, reflection can break most of the encapsulation logic.

Comment: It won't behave the same as java 8 even if illegal access is permitted.

Comment: True, with the addition of `module`s there has been a good amount of change. (and this has caused a great deal change in the mock frameworks used in unit tests). I haven't worked much on these latest changes though. Thank you for the good discussion.

Answer (score 3):

Change `Arrays.sort(s5.toCharArray());`
To
 `char[]  s6 = s5.toCharArray()): Arrays.sort(s6);`

Then print the values of s6

toCharArray() gives you a new array from the source but doesn't modify the source. When you print you are printing the source array not the array containing the sorted char

Comment: And, importantly, Java `String`s are immutable.  There is no other way to reorder the characters of one, either.

Comment: What result do you expect from `s6.toCharArray()`?

Comment: I think it should be:  char[]  s6 = s5.toCharArray()): Arrays.sort(s6);

Comment: @john thanks for pointing out. Modified the code in answer

Answer (score 2):

The [Answer by Horse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66147371/642706) is correct. Your code is discarding a newly created array immediately after sorting. You passed a new anonymous array to `Arrays.sort`, which sorted that new array, and then the new array went out-of-scope, as you neglected to put the array into a variable.

In addition, I can show code using Unicode code points rather than `char`.

## Unicode code point numbers

The `char` type in Java is obsolete, unable to represent even half of the characters defined in Unicode. Instead, you should be working with the code point numbers, one number assigned to each character in the Unicode standard.

You can get a stream ([`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html)) of those integer code point numbers by calling [`String#codePoints`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#codePoints()).

Here is some example code. As an input we use a string that contains a couple of emoji characters. Using `char` type, we incorrectly see four `?` where we expect two character numbers. Then we use code points, and we correctly see a pair of numbers (128075, 128506) for the pair of emoji characters. Lastly, we use Java streams to sort the code point numbers, and collect the sorted numbers to build a new `String` object.

```java
String input = " Hello World.";
System.out.println( "input = " + input );

// Wrong way, using obsolete `char` type.
char[] chars = input.toCharArray();
System.out.println( "chars before sort: " + Arrays.toString( chars ) );  // Notice that we get *four* `?` where we expect *two* letters (each of two emoji).
Arrays.sort( chars );
System.out.println( "chars after sort: " + Arrays.toString( chars ) );

// Examining code points.
System.out.println( "Print the code point number for each letter in the string. Notice we get *two* larger numbers, one for each emoji." );
input.codePoints().forEach( System.out :: println );

// Sorting by code point numbers.
String sorted =
        input
                .codePoints()
                .sorted()
                .collect( StringBuilder :: new , StringBuilder :: appendCodePoint , StringBuilder :: append )
                .toString();
System.out.println( "sorted = " + sorted );
```

When run.

```
input =  Hello World.
chars before sort: [?, ?, ?, ?,  , H, e, l, l, o,  , W, o, r, l, d, .]
chars after sort: [ ,  , ., H, W, d, e, l, l, l, o, o, r, ?, ?, ?, ?]
Print the code point number for each letter in the string. Notice we get *two* larger numbers, one for each emoji.
128075
128506
32
72
101
108
108
111
32
87
111
114
108
100
46
sorted =   .HWdellloor
```

The first two characters in `sorted` are actually SPACE characters, originally found between the words in `input`.

Instead of the streams, we could use arrays.

```java
int[] codePoints = input.codePoints().toArray();
System.out.println( "codePoints before sorting = " + Arrays.toString( codePoints ) );
Arrays.sort( codePoints );
System.out.println( "codePoints after sorting = " + Arrays.toString( codePoints ) );
```

When run. Notice how the `32` number twice represents the two SPACE characters.

```
codePoints before sorting = [128075, 128506, 32, 72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 87, 111, 114, 108, 100, 46]
codePoints after sorting = [32, 32, 46, 72, 87, 100, 101, 108, 108, 108, 111, 111, 114, 128075, 128506]
```

For more info, read [*The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)*](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).

Comment: This is the complete answer in the context of internalization. Java's contract to `char` as a 16-bit unsigned type has limited the evolution of the current `String` methods ability to transparently handle unicode characters(codepoints). There are methods in `String` that can help us achieve the desired `length` and `substring` methods. It requires a slight perspective change. May be Java should introduce a `UnicodeString`  class to completely overhaul this behavior.